# magento 1.9 rwd front page show more than 5 new products

Tags: product, frontend

i'm exploring the magento 1.9.1 front page. By default it shows only five products, i tried alter the source, but `<?php echo count($_products->getItems()); ?>` only return 5, there should be 7 new products should be shown

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-products">
        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
        <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
        <?php $i=0; ?>
        <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col-widget">
        <?php echo count($_products->getItems()); ?>
            <?php foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
                <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <?php // The image size is locked at 210 for this for display purposes. CSS has it at 75% which should equate to 278px?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(210) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>)"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <ul class="add-to-links">
                                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i want to show more than 5 products, any ideas?

Comment: What is the "alteration" that you have done ? how did you add 2 extra products into the collection. Please provide more details on this.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/z7uptm0l7/

Answer (score 1):

i found this is a widget,

i just found this is  a called widget `{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}` in cms page,

just change the product count can adjust the products to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

New products block defined via layout xml

To update products count you need to

login to admin

go to cms edit page

switch to design tab

update "Layout Update XML" to

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="setProductsCount"><count>7</count></action>
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>6</count></action>
</block>
```